# Div as modal - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, background, modal-dialog

I need a JavaScript that shows hidden div on the center of the screen as modal with darked background like jquery dialog!

example:

```
<div id='divToShow' style='display:none'>

Here is the content of the div that should be shown as modal on the center of the page!

</div>
```

Who can help? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

A simple modal pop up div or dialog box can be done by CSS properties and little bit of jQuery.The basic idea is simple:

1. Create a div with semi transparent background & show it on top of your content page on click.

2. Show your pop up div or alert div on top of the semi transparent dimming/hiding div.

So we need three divs:

content(main content of the site).

hider(To dim the content).

popup_box(the modal div to display).

First let us define the CSS:

```
    #hider
    {
        position:absolute;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width:1600px;
        height:2000px;
        margin-top: -800px; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
        margin-left: -500px; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
        /*
        z- index must be lower than pop up box
       */
        z-index: 99;
       background-color:Black;
       //for transparency
       opacity:0.6;
    }

    #popup_box  
    {

    position:absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width:10em;
        height:10em;
        margin-top: -5em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
        margin-left: -5em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border:  2px solid black;
        z-index:100; 

    }
```

It is important that we set our hider div's z-index lower than pop_up box as we want to show popup_box on top.

Here comes the java Script:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        //hide hider and popup_box
        $("#hider").hide();
        $("#popup_box").hide();

        //on click show the hider div and the message
        $("#showpopup").click(function () {
            $("#hider").fadeIn("slow");
            $('#popup_box').fadeIn("slow");
        });
        //on click hide the message and the
        $("#buttonClose").click(function () {

            $("#hider").fadeOut("slow");
            $('#popup_box').fadeOut("slow");
        });

        });
```

And finally the HTML:

```
<div id="hider"></div>
<div id="popup_box">
    Message<br />
    <a id="buttonClose">Close</a>
</div>    
<div id="content">
    Page's main content.<br />
    <a id="showpopup">ClickMe</a>
</div>
```

I have used jquery-1.4.1.min.js www.jquery.com/download and tested the code in Firefox. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a jfiddle example of a modal overlay using jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/r77K8/1/

Hope this gets you started.

Bob

Comment: Nothing to understand, what and where should I dowload to use that examples?

Comment: This is an example with a hidden div that is shown when you click the link. This example uses jQuery. All the code (html, css, javascript) is in the example.

Comment: Hi, that is something like i need, but how can I change position of modal window there?

Comment: Here is an update with the ability to position the modal div. http://jsfiddle.net/r77K8/4/

Comment: Not sure if this is a standard technique/approach but I like it a lot. Thanks rcravens!